# How to do a second query using the results of a previous query

Tags: mysql

Ok I need to count how many sales has made each of the sell agents of the company, so I do This...

```
SELECT agentID, AgentName, COUNT(*) as total_sales FROM sales GROUP BY agentID
```

This works perfectly, how ever It does not show the agents that had 0 sells.

So I need to perform a

```
SELECT agentID FROM agents
```

and the do a query of each result, so I can count how many sales had that agent. I hope I explain it.

(I can do the loop in PHP, how ever Im wondering if is possible to do directly in MySQL)

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you want with one query:

```
select a.agentId, a.agentName, count(s.agentId) as total_sales
from agents a left outer join
     sales s
     on a.agentId = s.agentId
group by a.agentId, a.agentName;
```

The `left outer join` keeps everything in the first table (`agents`).  The `count()` is counting the number of matches in the `sales` table.

Comment: @Dragnovich . . . Those are called table aliases.  In this case, they are not strictly needed (they are required for self-joins and other cases where two tables in the `from` clause have the same columns).  However, they make the query more readable.  And, by using them for all column names, ensures that the column sources are unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine these:

```
SELECT agents.agentID, AgentName, COUNT(sales.id) as total_sales 
FROM 
agents 
LEFT JOIN sales ON (sales.agentId = agents.agentId)
GROUP BY agentID
```